# How to limit the number of nodes created using the Feeds module?

Tags: 7, feeds

I want to limit the number of node created by the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module, it hsould be limited to 5 each time.

I've added `$conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 5;` to the bottom of `sites/default/settings.php`

I've also changed `FEEDS_PROCESS_LIMIT` value in `plugins/FeedsProcessor.inc` to be `5`

But still Feeds trying to import more than 5.

Looks like I've missed something. Anybody any hints about it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to clear your **caches** after setting `$conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 50;`.

Alternatively, if you are just looking for a quick **limiter** (during development of a custom importer, for example) this trick worked for me: 
[Limit number of feed items to import ($conf['feeds_process_limit'] not working)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1909974) (an `active` issue in the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) issue queue).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting $conf['feeds_node_batch_size'] in your settings.php file. It looks like that is one of the variables that the feeds module [looks at](http://drupalcode.org/project/feeds.git/blob/b63d9c7deca75430c04b92528651dab552216cbe:/plugins/FeedsNodeProcessor.inc#l29) to determine how many items to process in each batch.

Comment: Isn't `feeds_node_batch_size` is applicable in Drupal 6? From readme: `Variable 'feeds_node_batch_size' is now called 'feeds_process_limit'`